# Is configuration variable to disable signals in kernel needed?

Tags: kernel, signals

While configuring semi-posix Nuttx kernel, came across CONFIG_DISABLE_SIGNALS to disable all signals. Not sure if this is same with Linux as well.

What is the use of having a kernel with signals disabled?
If not useful, why have this configuration variable?

Could have asked in Nuttx forum to know Nuttx specifics, but I am interested across kernels.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the NuttX specifics:  I have CONFIG_DISABLE_SIGNALS but it does reduce the minimal code footprint by about 3KiB.  That is important for people working on really hardware with very minimal resources.  I tried to get rid of it once and just pissed off a lot of people.